# NLog MySql .Net Core 3.0 logging not saving to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, nlog, .net-core-3.0

I have setup NLog on my project that will save the logging to my audit database (separate from the default database). However, it is failing to write to the database. I have a console logger target as well and that is logging as expected. No errors are shown or given. It merely fails to write to the database.

I have tried various methods provided from google, but none seemed to have worked. I have also tried using NLogBuilder to configure the config for that specific controller but still, it doesn't write to the database

**nlog.config file:**

```
<configSections>  
  <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />  
</configSections> 
<nlog internalLogLevel="Trace">
  <targets>
    <target name="ConsoleLogger" type="Console" 
      layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"/>
    <target name="DatabaseLog" type="Database">
      <commandtext>
        INSERT INTO Logs 
        (LogDate, LogLevel, Message, Exception) 
        VALUES 
        (@log_date, @log_level, @message, @exception)
      </commandtext>

      <parameter name="@log_date" 
                 layout="${log_date}" 
                 dbType="DateTime"/>
      <parameter name="@thread" 
                 layout="${thread}" 
                 dbType="String"
                 size="255"/>
      <parameter name="@log_level" 
                 layout="${log_level}"
                 dbType="String"
                 size="20" />
      <parameter name="@logger" 
                 layout="${logger}"
                 dbType="String"
                 size="250" />
      <parameter name="@message" 
                 layout="${message}"
                 dbType="String"
                 size="4000" />
      <parameter name="@exception" 
                 layout="${exception}"
                 dbType="String"
                 size="4000" />

      <dbProvider>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data</dbProvider>
      <connectionString>User Id=username;Password=password;Host=localhost;Database=audit_database;TreatTinyAsBoolean=false</connectionString>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Fatal" writeTo="ConsoleLogger,DatabaseLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Controller method:**

```
public static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(typeof(ActionerController));

_logger.Info("text");
```

**Main.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
      logging.ClearProviders();
      logging.AddNLog();
    }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
      config
        .AddJsonFile($"environment-mount/appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Comment: .NET Core doesn't use `app.config` files and NLog's config file doesn't need `configSections`. In fact, this is an invalid XML file because it has *two* root elements. [This example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#2-create-a-nlogconfig-file) shows what `nlog.config` should look like

Comment: Have you checked [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core 3](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3) in NLog's repo?

Comment: I went through getting started, I left out the usage of the dependency injected logger. Added that in. Fixed the config as suggested, but it still won't log to the database. It only logs to the console and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, make sure you have installed the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) package.

There are also some mistakes in your config and code:

- `${log_date}`, `${log_level}` and `${thread}` don't exist. I guess you mean `${date}`, `${level}` and `${threadid}`. See all options [here](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers).
- `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger` with an argument expects a logger type - so inherits from `NLog.Logger`. I think you are looking for  `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` or `LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ActionerController).FullName)`. See [API docs](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.6.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetCurrentClassLogger_1.htm)

Of course there could be other errors, e.g. a wrong query, mistyped colum names or wrong column types. NLog could of course tell you the problem:

- Or enable exceptions. In your config `<nlog throwExceptions=true >`
- Or enable the internal log: `<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Warn">`. Read more [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging)

Comment: Logging to the file helped to refine where the error was happening due to adding in the throw exceptions true. Changing thread to thread id worked as well. It was a syntax error in the sql string that was stopping the writing. The correct answer is both this and the comments from Panagiotis Kanavos.